# pm2 not starting index.js server

Tags: node.js, express, production-environment, pm2, pm2-logrotate

I am running a nodejs server.
When I run it with the command "node index.js" the app run fine.
But when I run it using pm2 -> "pm2 start index.js"
pm2 outputs that the app is online but it isn't.
Also when I check about it using the command 'pm2 status', no running app is showed.

This problem occurred after I made some changes  in my "index.js".
But reverting the "index.js" file to the previous working (index.js) with pm2 is also not working now.

Below is the screen shot, please help.
[image]

Comment: Are you running the app on a docker container?

Comment: Try `pm2 list` instead of `pm2 status` to check the list of running apps. I guess you also have to stop running app, and then run again to make changes affect

Comment: The output of **pm2 list** is same as of pm2 status as shown in the screenshot. @rashad

Comment: @Chris, I am not running the app on a docker container. Its simple either I do **node index.js** or **pm2 start index.js**

Comment: Also somehow now when I run my previous version of **index.js**, the pm2 is working fine and running the app ,idk what is wrong please help.

Comment: Do your index.js files have any difference in the `port`?

Comment: Nope, it listens on 443 and 80, 80 just redirects to 443

Comment: Can you post snippets of your old and new `index.js`?